# Combining the output of two models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, predictive-modeling

I have two models that predict a person's activity (seating, walking, taking stairs, and sleeping) based on a person's motion and the video. `Model 1` is trained on a video dataset while `Model 2` is trained on a motion dataset. Each model can independently predict a person's activity. However, I would like to make the final prediction based on the consensus of the two models. For example, if `Model 1` predict a `walk` class and `Model 2`predicts a `walk` then the final prediction would be `walk`. However, if any of the two models disagree, the final prediction would be `unknown`. Obviously, this can be achieved with simple `if statements` but I was wondering if there is any out of the box way to do this in `python` or if there is a known best approach to do this.

Comment: If you're setting a hard-rule (If different Then unknown), just use a if. You could however train a third supervised model to weight the predictions of your two models, but if that's not necessary it can be overengineering. This kind of "ensemble" is especially relevant if your models output scores/probabilities instead of discrete classes.

Comment: @Mephy assuming my classes output probabilities, how can I implement this elegantly?

Comment: If you're using Python, assuming you're using the scipy environment, you can use `sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier` with argument `voting='soft'`. However it does not implement weight training and instead takes weights as a hyperparameter; you can use an optimization method to fit the weights (maybe even a simple grid search, but you can get fancy with a gaussian process or evolutionary algorithm).